# How can I call a function with parameters without using an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following Problem, I want to call a function `b` like I call the function `a`.
Here is the example:

```
$('#clickme').click(function () {
  console.log("abc");
});

function a() {
  console.log("a");
}
function b(b) {
  console.log(b);
}

$('#clickmea').click(a);

// how to call this method without using a anonymous function?
$('#clickmeb').click(b("ab"));
```

Or is it not possible to call `b("ab")` without using a anonymous function?

[JSBin exmaple](http://jsbin.com/dagayaqitose/1/)

Comment: You can't do that _"without using a anonymous function"_

Comment: You can currify the function b, but for that you need a function (anonymous or not) that passes the desired arguments to `b` when called. If you use a library for this, under the hood the same is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without using either a anonymous function:

```
$('#clickmeb').click(function(){b("ab")});
```

Or a wrapper function:

```
function callback(){
    b("ab")
}
$('#clickmeb').click(callback);
```

There's no need to return a anonymous function from the callback. That's just extra code that doesn't do anything useful.

In fact, it wouldn't carry over variables passed to the callback:

```
function callback(){
    return function(){
        b("ab") // There will be no arguments passed to this anonymous function, unless you explicitly add them. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can use a library to partially apply the function `b`, which at the end it's just using an anonymous function.

Comment: @Marty: That's not a valid edit. You you elaborate on your reason to do so?

Comment: I don't see how a line that calls out another answer as being poor in your own answer is necessary.

Comment: So, you take matters into your own hands and just remove the line. You could just have posted a comment about it. I'll just leave out the comment that that's what the other answer suggests, @Marty.

Comment: It was an attempt at saving you from looking like a poor sport by specifically saying that other answers did something you didn't agree with. It reads OK now I suppose.